# Program to build adaptive mesh (triangles in 2D and tetrahedron in 3D) for Finite Element Method in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, finite-element-analysis

I'm writting a Fotran code of Finite Elements Method and I need some program to generate adaptive meshes inside my program (that is: without read/write input/output files). This meshes are to calculate aposteriori errors.

I tried to use [triangle software](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html), but is wrote in C, and I had problems calling from fortran (creating an interface...).

Preferably, I'm looking for something in Fortran90 or higher, but if is wrote in Fortran 77 I thing that I could use to.

Comment: Asking for Fortran code recommendations may be viewed as off topic, but if you ask about your specific problems with interfacing with the C that may be seen more favourably.

Comment: Thanks @francescalus for comment. But I mentioned that C mesh generator program just for explain that I'm looking for something similar but in Fortran.

Comment: Are people still writing FEA code in FORTRAN?  Amazing.  I would have expected a more modern language and greater leverage of multiple cores and parallelism.

Comment: I thing that you are taking about some older Fortran version, because Fortran still rocks on scientific computing, in its modern version of course. It has all new toys of other languajes, and is really faster.

Answer (score -1):

it has nothing to do with the language. Just call the excutagble file in your program.

Comment: In this case is not possible because the input of the C program is a (big and complicated) structure, so you must to define that structure in Fortran (the main program), send as input in the C program, and then recovery the output structure in the Fortran code. The main problem is that there is an array with unknown length that is output of the C program, and until now that is not allowed in Fortran.